# Use JScript to insert Price List on Quote onOpen in Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

Here is my code, I get an object error onLoad. Please help.

```
function Setlook()
{

var lookup = new Object();
var lookupValue = new Array();
lookup.id = "7b31D4D998-F124-E111-96C3-1CC1DEEA";
lookup.entityType = 1022;
lookup.name = "Default";
lookupValue[0] = lookup;
Xrm.Page.getAttribute(“pricelevelid”).setValue(lookupValue);

}
```

Comment: The quote marks here... getAttribute(“pricelevelid”) ...don't look right... Compare “ ” to " ". Not sure it makes a difference or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the proper syntax, the important thing is to have the correct .typename

```
function Setlook()
{


var value = new Array();
value[0] = new Object();
value[0].id = '{31D4D998-F124-E111-96C3-1CC1DEE8EC2D}';
value[0].name = 'Default';
value[0].typename = 'pricelevel';

Xrm.Page.getAttribute("pricelevelid").setValue(value);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code itself looks correct, but the GUID of the lookup doesn't. It doesn't have the right format nor does it have the right number of characters (32). Fixing that should eliminate the error.

Comment: id=%7b31D4D998-F124-E111-96C3-1CC1DEE8EA2D%7d> can anyone tell me what part of this is the id. I think I must be picking up the wrong 32 characters. Please help

Comment: @Andrew: From Wikipedia, "The value of a GUID is represented as a 32-character hexadecimal string, such as {21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}". "%7b" is the URL escape code for "{", and "%7d" is the escape code for "}", so together, your GUID is `31D4D998-F124-E111-96C3-1CC1DEE8EA2D` or `{31D4D998-F124-E111-96C3-1CC1DEE8EA2D}`.